# How to allow Bitbucket-Pipelines to pull images from Amazon EC2 container service (ECR)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket-pipelines

**What I have tried:**

- I can successfully push to Amazon ECR (details in [this answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983108/1782641))
- I am failing to pull the above image in a subsequent pipeline (see example).

**Example bitbucket-pipeline.yml**

```
image:
  name: <ecr-registry-address>/<repository>:<tag>
  aws:
    access-key: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    secret-key: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo 'Hello World'
```

**The error I get back:**

[image: Currently getting this error, not much of an explanation]

**Finally:**

In order to push to the repository, I already setup IAM roles for the bitbucket-pipelines account ([AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecr_managed_policies.html#AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser)). Is there any other setup required?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the cause for the above error was the ${} format. Removing the curly brackets allowed everything to work as expected.

[More details here.](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-allow-Bitbucket-Pipelines-to-pull-images-from-Amazon-EC2/qaq-p/633458)